# How to wrap grid item to full width with one column taking 2 spans in an auto-fit grid-column-template

Tags: css, css-grid, styled-components

I am using styled-components but I think that won't make much of a difference. What I want to do is to make the grid automatically align to row width. When I apply 2 span for the preceding column, the following column does not wrap to full width on a certain range of view port width. After, I decrease the view port more then it goes back to what I want. How can I fix this without using media queries and flexbox? I know this can be fixed with media queries but I want to do it without it.

[image: gif]

```
const LogoContact = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 150px;
`;

const Logo = styled.div`
  background-color: #a85218;
  grid-column: span 2;
  color: white;
`;

const Contact = styled.div`
  background-color: #d0507e;
  color: white;
`;
```

LogoContact is the parent container and Logo is for the column that takes 2 spans. Contact div is what I want to fix.

Comment: I see you edited to mention you don't want to use media queries, which was one of the options I gave. But what about my flexbox solution, does that not solve your problem or do you have to use grid?

Comment: Sorry, for not adding the "edit: ". I wanted to do it with only css grid. I understand if grid does not have that functionality then flex is the best way. I am just learning CSS grid so I have knowledge about flex and know with flex-wrap it does not even need me asking this question. So, Thank you for answering the question and Yes, I want a grid only solution. @CvP

Comment: I think if you want a grid only solution, media queries is basically your only option. Your problem is that you are trying to fight how css grid works, so there will not be an elegant solution as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using media queries and give the contact div a span of 2 when between 300 and 600 screenwidth.

A better solution would be using flexbox instead of grid. Here's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      /* https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/ */
      html {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      *,
      *:before,
      *:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
      }

      #logoContact {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

      #logo {
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 600px;
        background-color: #a85218;
        flex: 2 1;
        color: white;
      }

      #contact {
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 300px;
        flex: 1 1;
        background-color: #d0507e;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="logoContact">
      <div id="logo">logo</div>
      <div id="contact">contact</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```